# Reading in monetary amounts by text file & calculating bill denominations

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I am supposed to read a text file into a java program, add the monetary amounts in the java file and then determine how to pay each total amount (read $20, $10, $5...). I am having trouble how to tackle separating each line of the text file for separate calculations.

This is the text file I am importing:

```
Class1  9.30    7.44    5.32    3.33
Class2  2.22
Class3  7.33    4.44    3.56
Class4  15.67   12.02   10.33   8.87
Class5  4.44    3.33    2.22    1.11
```

I am supposed to show solutions not only for each value, but for each class. I'm assuming some sort of for loop is required but I'm not able to figure it out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\idhit\\Desktop\\amounts.txt");
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(file);

    String st = bf.readLine();

    double sum = 0;
    double c1total = 0;
    double c2total = 0;
    double c3total = 0;
    double c4total = 0;
    double c5total = 0;

    while ((st = bf.readLine()) != null) {

        StringTokenizer stn = new StringTokenizer(st);
        String rn = stn.nextToken();
        String name = stn.nextToken();
        double c1 = Double.parseDouble(stn.nextToken());
        double c2 = Double.parseDouble(stn.nextToken());
        double c3 = Double.parseDouble(stn.nextToken());
        double c4 = Double.parseDouble(stn.nextToken());
        double c5 = Double.parseDouble(stn.nextToken());

    }

    double value = scan.nextDouble();
    int valueIntegral = (int) value;
    int valueFractional = (int) Math.round(100 * value - 100 * valueIntegral);

    // Integral values

    int hundred = valueIntegral / 100;

    int fifty = (valueIntegral % 100) / 50;

    int twenty = ((valueIntegral % 100) % 50) / 20;

    int ten = (((valueIntegral % 100) % 50) % 20) / 10;

    int five = ((((valueIntegral % 100) % 50) % 20) % 10) / 5;

    int one = (((((valueIntegral % 100) % 50) % 20) % 10) % 5) / 1;

    // Fractional values

    int quarter = valueFractional / 25;

    int dime = (valueFractional % 25) / 10;

    int nickel = ((valueFractional % 25) % 10) / 5;

    int penny = (((valueFractional % 25) % 10) % 5) / 1;

    System.out.println(hundred + " hundred dollar bills\n" + fifty + " fifty dollar bills\n" + twenty
            + " twenty dollar bills\n" + ten + " ten dollar bills\n" + five + " five dollar bills\n" + one
            + " one dollar bills\n" + quarter + " quarters\n" + dime + " dimes\n" + nickel + " nickels\n" + penny
            + " pennies");
}
```

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Be aware that your calculation of `valueFractional` is subject to floating point errors, and will sometimes give a result that's one cent too small.

Comment: Please check the update answer as well.

Comment: Yes, I think this works.  Just ran into an 'illegal start of expression'.   Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were in the right direction however to assign total to each class based on name you need some condition. Lets say your `bufferedReader` reads line 1 which is

```
Class1  9.30    7.44    5.32    3.33
```

From StringTokenizer you can get name and the total money from each class.
Each time when you call `.nextToken()` it reads up to the next delimiter. In your case it is whitespace. First `.nextToken()` will read `Class1`. Second one will read `9.30` and so on...

```
Class 1: 25.39
```

From here you could go like if name is `Class1` put total in `c1total`. Ring any bells? Yes you guessed it right. You would use if statement here. Since you have 5 classes you have 5 if statements. Each while of yours will handle each line and assign it to correct variable utilizing if statements.

I would suggest you to try what I wrote above however I did the same thing in a different way just to give you a perceptive and how you can program same thing differently and quite possibly even better.

**Edit:** Like DawoodibnKareem suggested. `StringTokenizer` is legacy and should not be used. I have update the code. It now utilizes split and  [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of double.

```
// Instead of 5 variables I created an array to store data
BigDecimal[] classTotal = new BigDecimal[5];
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] lineSplit = line.split("\\s+");
    // Class1 9.30 7.44 5.32 3.33 would become
    // [Class1, 9.30, 7.44, 5.32, 3.33]
    String name = lineSplit[0];
    switch (name) {
    case "Class1":
        classTotal[0] = getSum(lineSplit);
        break;
    case "Class2":
        classTotal[1] = getSum(lineSplit);
        break;
    case "Class3":
        classTotal[2] = getSum(lineSplit);
        break;
    case "Class4":
        classTotal[3] = getSum(lineSplit);
        break;
    case "Class5":
        classTotal[4] = getSum(lineSplit);
        break;

    }
}
bufferedReader.close();
for (int i = 0; i < classTotal.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Class " + (i + 1) + " : " + classTotal[i]);
}

public static BigDecimal getSum(String[] line) {
    BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0);
    // Iterating from index 1 because 0 index contains name
    for (int i = 1; i < line.length; i++) {
        BigDecimal valueBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(line[i]);
        sum = sum.add(valueBigDecimal);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Class 1 : 25.39
Class 2 : 2.22
Class 3 : 15.33
Class 4 : 46.89
Class 5 : 11.10
```

**Output:** (If I use double instead of BigDecimal)

```
Class 1 : 25.39
Class 2 : 2.22
Class 3 : 15.33
Class 4 : 46.88999999999999
Class 5 : 11.1
```

Notice how some values are off especially for `Class 4` which should be `46.89`.

This is because float and double primitive types in Java are [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) numbers, where the number is stored as a binary representation of a fraction and a exponent. Floating point numbers some times (safe to assume "most of the time") are not be able to return an exact representation of a number. Hence you get `46.88999999999999` instead of `46.89`. This is why double/float are considered horrible for calculating currency. To avoid this issue we have to use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Especially in you case where further performing calculation on double will just worsen the precision.

Comment: Be aware of what the Javadoc says about the `StringTokenizer` class - "... StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead. ...".  In this case, using a `Scanner`, the way OP was originally using it, is a better option.  Also, the addition in this solution is subject to floating point rounding errors, and will frequently give the wrong results.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem You are right. I'll update my code to use better class and will add information regarding `floating point rounding errors`.

Comment: I understand what you were taking about @Goion. I'm still working on output but thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah, that's much better.